# MongoDB inconsistent read results

Tags: mongodb

I'm accessing a mongodb with a large amount of entries (~300M).
I am looking for certain entries that are only a small fraction of the total.

When I use `db.collection.find()` I don't always get the same results.
I know that the database is not being updated. Sometimes, I can find some of the records I am looking for, but sometimes mongodb does not give me any result. I do not really understand how mongodb sorts the entries to process, nor why I don't get consistent results.

Comment: Is there any sample code you can show us that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I'm using db.collection.find({field 1: {field1a : true}})

Comment: That query will only match a document where `field1` is exactly the object `{field1a: true}` with no other fields.  Was that the intent?

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. There are other fields. How can I do a partial match ?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer rather than putting it in the question and adding "solved" to the title. This way you can click the green checkmark to accept your answer which will properly mark the question as solved. It is fine--encouraged, even--to answer your own question if none of the other answers are satisfactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do the partial match.

I did db.collection.find{"field1.field1a" :true} )

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is bizarre. But you shouldn't do it that way. The better way to query is:

- within your find request, define your filter criteria
- define a sort
- use an index to support your query and sort